# SPARK - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to run jar file using spark-submit.

```
han-ui-MacBook-Air:spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 Alphahacker$ ./bin/spark-submit --class SimpleApp --master local[*] /Users/Alphahacker/IdeaProjects/sparksimpletest/target/spark-simple-test-1.0.jar
```

But I got error message as below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:712)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My IntelliJ screen looks like this: [Program structure in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIjJd.png)
, And pom.xml of this project as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>alpha.spark.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-simple-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10:spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>twitter4j-stream:twitter4j-stream</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Program code is like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleApp").setMaster(args(0))
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val filePath = "/Users/Alphahacker/Desktop/README.md"
    val inputRDD = sc.textFile(filePath)
    val matchTerm = "spark"
    val numMatches = inputRDD.filter(_.contains(matchTerm)).count()
    println("%s lines in %s contains %s".format(numMatches, filePath, matchTerm))
    System.exit(0)
  }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong.
As you can see in the picture above, I wrote SimpleApp object without package and I built the project using Maven. And I thought I made the command properly.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you show your program code? Maybe your `SimpleApp` class is within a package? Then you have to specify the full qualified name in the `--class` option.

Comment: is `SimpleApp` without a package? if not provide fully qualified class name in the command line like `spark-submit --class com.spark.example.SimpleApp`

Comment: @hage
I just added the program code in the post. as you can see the SimpleApp class is not within any packages.

Comment: @diginoise 
the SimpleApp is not within any packages. I just added the SimpleApp code in the post.

Comment: Your program runs fine on my machine. I built it without maven, though.

Comment: @hage when I run the program on the IntelliJ, it runs fine. But, if I run the jar file extracted from the program using spark-submit, the error messages occur.

Comment: @Seung-heeHan you could inspect the generated file. Maybe you find something...

Comment: @Seung-heeHan, Try `MANIFEST.MF` inside jar whether you have your class file  name inside it

Answer (score 0):

you have to save your java files in your directory with this folder structure `src/main/java/example.java` and build with maven. This method solves my error which is very similar to yours.