# spark submit error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myCompany.scala.MaxPrice

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am unable to submit the spark job.

my code is maxPrice.scala which is working fine on Intellij
all i am trying to do is simply submit a job on spark

```
package com.myCompany.scala

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}

object MaxPrice {
  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Max Price").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println("hello")
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

I have tried all suggestions from google and actually not able to resolve it.

POM file:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myCompany.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>sparkExample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.10.6</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>2.11</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Error when i submit the job

```
hadoop@namenode1:~/softwares$ spark-submit --class com.myCompany.scala.MaxPrice spark.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myCompany.scala.MaxPrice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:712)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

On Intellij code run result is

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:D:\ide\ideaIC-2018.2.5.win\lib\idea_rt.jar=53736:D:\ide\ideaIC-2018.2.5.win\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\spark\target\classes;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.6\scala-library-2.10.6.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.10\1.6.1\spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-mapred\1.7.7\avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.7\avro-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill_2.10\0.5.0\chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\kryo\kryo\2.21\kryo-2.21.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\reflectasm\reflectasm\1.07\reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\minlog\minlog\1.2\minlog-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill-java\0.5.0\chill-java-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.4\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-client\2.2.0\hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.2.0\hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.1\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\xmlenc\xmlenc\0.52\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-auth\2.2.0\hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.4.1\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.0\xz-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs\2.2.0\hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-client\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-test-framework\jersey-test-framework-grizzly2\1.9\jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-test-framework\jersey-test-framework-core\1.9\jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-client\1.9\jersey-client-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-grizzly2\1.9\jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http\2.1.2\grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-framework\2.1.2\grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\gmbal\gmbal-api-only\3.0.0-b023\gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\external\management-api\3.0.0-b012\management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http-server\2.1.2\grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-rcm\2.1.2\grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http-servlet\2.1.2\grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.servlet\3.1\javax.servlet-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-json\1.9\jersey-json-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.1\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.2\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.8.3\jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.8.3\jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\contribs\jersey-guice\1.9\jersey-guice-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-server-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-annotations\2.2.0\hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-launcher_2.10\1.6.1\spark-launcher_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-common_2.10\1.6.1\spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.10\1.6.1\spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\leveldbjni\leveldbjni-all\1.8\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.4.4\jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-unsafe_2.10\1.6.1\spark-unsafe_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jets3t\jets3t\0.7.1\jets3t-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-recipes\2.4.0\curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-framework\2.4.0\curator-framework-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-client\2.4.0\curator-client-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.4.5\zookeeper-3.4.5.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\jline\jline\0.9.94\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0.1\guava-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.servlet\3.0.0.v201112011016\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.4.1\commons-math3-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.10\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.10\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.10\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.10\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.3\compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2\snappy-java-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\roaringbitmap\RoaringBitmap\0.5.11\RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\2.2\commons-net-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-remote_2.10\2.3.11\akka-remote_2.10-2.3.11.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-actor_2.10\2.3.11\akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\config\1.2.1\config-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.8.0.Final\netty-3.8.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\uncommons\maths\uncommons-maths\1.2.2a\uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-slf4j_2.10\2.3.11\akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.11.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-jackson_2.10\3.2.10\json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-core_2.10\3.2.10\json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-ast_2.10\3.2.10\json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scalap\2.10.0\scalap-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.0\scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-server\1.9\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-core\1.9\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\mesos\mesos\0.21.1\mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.29.Final\netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\clearspring\analytics\stream\2.7.0\stream-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.1.2\metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.1.2\metrics-json-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-graphite\3.1.2\metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.4.4\jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.4\jackson-core-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-scala_2.10\2.4.4\jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.10.4\scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.6\paranamer-2.6.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\apache\ivy\ivy\2.4.0\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-client\0.8.2\tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-hdfs\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-s3\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-local\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\net\razorvine\pyrolite\4.9\pyrolite-4.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.9\py4j-0.9.jar;C:\Users\Ashish\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\spark\unused\1.0.0\unused-1.0.0.jar" com.myCompany.scala.MaxPrice
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/11/14 18:02:00 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
18/11/14 18:02:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/11/14 18:02:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Ashish
18/11/14 18:02:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Ashish
18/11/14 18:02:00 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(Ashish); users with modify permissions: Set(Ashish)
18/11/14 18:02:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53773.
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.137.1:53786]
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 53786.
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-51899a3c-166a-47b3-bbaf-1afb4a76f2c4
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.4 GB
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.137.1:4040
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 53823.
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 53823
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:53823 with 2.4 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 53823)
18/11/14 18:02:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
hello
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.137.1:4040
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-9b01d15d-29db-4814-859e-227ef6b2950c
18/11/14 18:02:03 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

on ubuntu my versions are

```
Scala code runner version 2.10.5 
spark version 2.2.0**
```

however i can c class present in jar

```
hadoop@namenode1:~/softwares$ jar tvf spark.jar | grep MaxPrice
  1023 Tue Nov 13 21:58:40 IST 2018 com/myCompany/scala/MaxPrice$.class
   651 Tue Nov 13 21:58:40 IST 2018 com/myCompany/scala/MaxPrice.class
```

I can see 
[SPARK - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952258/spark-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

he also did not get answer but i am not able to upvote it as my credits are lesser.

Comment: can you try running with --master local[*]

Comment: no this did not work.  I tried what u said "spark-submit --master local[*] --class com.myCompany.scala.MaxPrice spark.jar"

Comment: did you try out the "--jars spark.jar" option?

Comment: No error is same